# Assemble command assembling zero pages

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, assemble

So I've been trying to use [Assemble](http://assemble.io) to build e-mails, and up until now it works; the problem is that now, when I try to run the Assemble command, it fails. Or, more accurately, it succeeds, with a message reading "0 pages assembled" despite no actual compiled files appearing. I'm honestly at a loss as to what the issue is here, as all of the options seem configured to point to the right folders (relative to the root directory where the gruntfile is located) and up until recently it was working.

I'm not really sure what's broken here; the relevant section of the grunt config object is excerpted below; the full config object is a little long to include in full here.

```
assemble: {
  'default': {
    options: {
      layoutdir: 'src/layouts'
    },
    pages: {
      src: ['src/emails/*.hbs'],
      dest: 'dist/'
    }
  }
}
```

Any thoughts on where I've gone wrong?

Comment: do you have a repository I can look at or a gist of the full gruntfile.js? What version of assemble are you using?

Comment: It's a work project so I can't release the source code; that said, it's based off of https://github.com/leemunroe/grunt-email-design with some modifications, specifically CDN and Cloudfiles tasks both removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

oh... you have too many layers in your `assemble` configuration. Remove the `'default'` object wrapping:

```
assemble: {
  options: {
    layoutdir: 'src/layouts'
  },
  pages: {
    src: ['src/emails/*.hbs'],
    dest: 'dist/'
  }
}
```

In this case, `options` is for all assemble targets, and `pages` is one of the targets.

Comment: Yep that was it exactly--got that working late last week and forgot to post the answer. Thanks for putting one up!